# Add color in a automatic generate Excel file

Tags: java, excel, colors, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a question about adding color in a Excel file.
I wonder if it's possible to do this with the methode ByteArrayOutputStream.

I've search but I didn't find anything.

```
/**
 * Export des incidents Jira
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
@GET
@Path("exportJiraIncidents")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response exportJiraIncidents() throws Exception {

    // Get data base data
    final List<IncidentVo> data = 
jiraGroupamaResource.getJiraIncidents();

    // csv export
    final ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new 
ByteArrayOutputStream();

    String line = "IssueId;Incident;Activité;DateCreation;Statut;"
+"RefIncJira;Intervenant;Titre;Gravité;resolution;" 
+ "updated;duedate;dateResolution;timeOriginalEstimate;timeEstimate;"
+ "timeSpent;workflow_id\r\n";

outStream.write(line.getBytes(Charset.forName("cp1252")));

    for (final IncidentVo vo : data) {

        line = addChampCsv(vo.getIssueId()) + 
addChampCsv(vo.getIncident()) + addChampCsv(vo.getActivite()) + 
addChampCsv(vo.getDateCreation())
                + addChampCsv(vo.getStatut()) + 
addChampCsv(vo.getRefIncJira()) + addChampCsv(vo.getIntervenant()) + 
addChampCsv(vo.getTitre())
                + addChampCsv(vo.getGravite()) + 
addChampCsv(vo.getResolution()) + addChampCsv(vo.getUpdated()) + 
addChampCsv(vo.getDueDate())
                + addChampCsv(vo.getDateResolution()) 
+ addChampCsv(vo.getTimeOriginalEstimate()) + 
addChampCsv(vo.getTimeEstimate())
                + addChampCsv(vo.getTimeSpent()) + 
addChampCsv(vo.getWorkflowId()) + "\r\n";

outStream.write(line.getBytes(Charset.forName("cp1252")));
    }

    return Response.ok(new 
ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray())).header(STR_TYPE_HEADER, "attachment; filename=incidents.csv")
            .type(STR_TYPE_CSV).build();
}
```

The 'string line = ' is the heading of the file and all the get in the loop put the info in the Excel file. 
I just don't get how to insert color.

Any idea ?

Comment: I would make use of [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to generate an excel file using Java

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced Excel sheet modifications from Java, you will probably have to use [JXL, the Java Excel API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JXL_(API))

There, you can quite easily do coloring, e.g.

```java
Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream);
workbook.createSheet(sheetName, 0);

WritableCell cell = sheet.getWritableCell(0,0);

WritableCellFormat coloredCellFormat = new WritableCellFormat();

coloredCellFormat.setBackground(Colour.RED);

cell.setCellFormat(newFormat);

workbook.write(); // important to use
workbook.close();
```

As you see in this example, JXL lets you write to any `OutputStream`. Therefore, you should be able to use it in your webservice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about this infortunatly, I need to use like I did in the post...